# Why does this give a Java compilation error: MyConsumer<String> implements Consumer<String>?

Tags: java, generics

The following code gives a compilation error:

```java
class MyConsumer<String> implements Consumer<String>{
    @Override
    public void accept(String s){
        System.out.println("hello".toUpperCase());
        System.out.println(s.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

The error:

```
ConsumerTest.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
                System.out.println(s.toUpperCase());
                                    ^
  symbol:   method toUpperCase()
  location: variable s of type String
  where String is a type-variable:
    String extends Object declared in class MyConsumer
```

This doesn't give any error:

```java
class MyConsumer implements Consumer<String>{
    @Override
    public void accept(String s){
        System.out.println("hello".toUpperCase());
        System.out.println(s.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 3):

You are implementing the Consumer interface shown below:

```
/**
 * Represents an operation that accepts a single input argument and returns no
 * result. Unlike most other functional interfaces, {@code Consumer} is expected
 * to operate via side-effects.
 *
 * <p>This is a <a href="package-summary.html">functional interface</a>
 * whose functional method is {@link #accept(Object)}.
 *
 * @param <T> the type of the input to the operation
 *
 * @since 1.8
 */
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Consumer<T>
```

This interface has a type parameter called T. To implement this interface one has to specify what the type parameter stands for. For example you can specify that you want to implement it with a String type parameter:

```
class MyConsumer implements Consumer<String>
```

Here the `<String>` means the type parameter T of Consumer is assumed at compile time to be a String.

Hence the overidden accept method has a String parameter:

```
@Override
public void accept(String s){
    System.out.println("hello".toUpperCase());
    System.out.println(s.toUpperCase());
}
```

This is all fine but when you do this:

```
class MyConsumer<String> implements Consumer<String>
```

You are introducing a new type parameter for the MyConsumer class, confusingly called 'String'. Now Consumer is no longer specifying the String class, but referring to the new type parameter. You get the same situation as this:

```
class MyConsumer<S> implements Consumer<S>{
    @Override
    public void accept(S s){
        System.out.println("hello".toUpperCase());
        System.out.println(s.toUpperCase()); // compilation error
    }
}
```

So this becomes a generic class, for which the type parameter still needs to be defined. Hence the compiler cannot match s.toUppercase().

You can prove this by fully qualifying the references to the String class:

```
public class MyConsumer<String> implements Consumer<java.lang.String> {
    @Override
    public void accept(java.lang.String s){
        System.out.println("hello".toUpperCase());
        System.out.println(s.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

(this compiles)

Answer (score 0):

Your class declares its own type `<String>`, which is why without it there is no error:

```
class MyConsumer implements Consumer<String> { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The first occurrence of `String` in this declaration...

```
class MyConsumer<String> implements Consumer<String>
```

...is just the name of a type parameter of `MyConsumer`. `String` in `class MyConsumer<String>` does not refer to `java.lang.String`. After all, this is syntactically the same as:

```
class MyConsumer<T> implements Consumer<String>
```

Then, in the `accept` method, you used `String` as the parameter type. This `String` *also* does not refer to `java.lang.String`. It instead refers to the type parameter named `String` you just declared. `java.lang.String`  is said to be [shadowed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4) by the type parameter `String`.

> Some declarations may be shadowed in part of their scope by another declaration of the same name, in which case a simple name cannot be used to refer to the declared entity.
>
> A declaration `d` of a type named `n` shadows the declarations of any other types named `n` that are in scope at the point where `d` occurs throughout the scope of `d`.

Since you want a consumer that consumes a `java.lang.String`, your class doesn't need to be generic.

If you actually want your class to be generic, *and* want to use `String` as the type parameter name for some weird reason, you should use the fully qualified name, `java.lang.String`, when declaring the parameter of `accept`.

```
@Override
public void accept(java.lang.String s){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first example `String` is just a "type name", just like T, K, V or so. During the compilation it becomes `Object` which does not have method `toUpperCase`. You should read about type erasure. In the second example you are telling the compiler that the type should be a String, so no problems in here.